# How to make a partition completely invisible to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

On the 64GB USB stick I carry with me, I have one 16.0GiB partition formatted fat32 (for stuff accessible via Windows) and the rest formatted with a full live copy of Linux Mint (not just the DVD live image, but a full live install, mounting the boot media read-write so I can plug it into any computer, use Linux, and then take the entire OS install with me).

Whenever I plug this USB stick into a Windows computer, it sees the FAT32 partition, and is able to read it.  The other partition (or two partitions - one is really tiny and I suspect it's the boot sector), however, doesn't contain a recognized filesystem, and must therefore be corrupt, so Windows helpfully suggests that I format it. Doing so would delete everything stored there, and I don't fancy doing data recovery on a deleted partition.

I worry that, shouild I leave my USB stick somewhere, and should someone plug it in, they would be prompted to format the two partitions that Windows was unable to make sense of.  I would like to suppress this dialog, preferably by somehow tricking Windows into not assigning a drive letter when the device is connected.  I should mention that simply removing the drive letter using Disk Manager or the registry would be insufficient as that would only affect a single system - it will be assigned a new drive letter when I, or someone who happens to find it, connects it to a different one.   I realize this may well involve deleting the partitions in question from the partition table entirely and then telling Linux "no really, there's a partition there" using a raw byte offset, probably also modifying the MBR to ensure it's still bootable without a valid partition layout.  I would prefer it didn't come to that, but I'm willing to try if anybody knows how.

I have access to both Windows and Linux as both virtual and physical machines and have been able to successfully boot from this stick in a VM.

Comment: Make a backup, then look here: https://serverfault.com/questions/591563/setting-the-hidden-attribute-on-a-partion-from-linux-parted-isnt-respected-b

Comment: What you want is not reliably possible - as it's forcing the OS to change the way it interacts with the USB stock, so it would need to run code, which any decent OS willnot allow to happen automatically.

Comment: You might be able to change the partition types of the partitions you wish to hide which might work with some OS's

Comment: This question was previously posted (and closed) [on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439206/80216).

Comment: Yes.  I was hoping it would be less off-topic here since this forum also deals with Windows.